how to select rows that are x characters shorter than longest
I have a study assignment and I've been banging my head in the wall for at least a day now.
I'm totally new to this and just learning the basics.
This is my assignment:
Use union to combine these queries:

Select customers whose city and postalcode both appear in suppliers table.
Select customers whose name is at most five characters shorter than the longest supplier name.

Northwind database in question.
This is what i tried:
select customername, customers.city, customers.postalcode
from customers 
join suppliers on customers.city = suppliers.city and customers.PostalCode = suppliers.PostalCode
union
select customername, customers.city, customers.postalcode
from customers 
where length(customername) < 
    (select max(length(suppliername)) 
    from suppliers)

Problem is that last "where clause".
I know that the longest suppliername has 38 characters:
(select max(length(suppliername))
from suppliers)    =38 characters
But i don't know how to query that "at most five characters shorter".
I get correct result set by querying:
where length(customername) > 33
but obviously that's not what is asked for.
Thank you for the help :)

This is Access, right? If so: Don't post it under MySQL, these are different languages.

And why not just; where length(customername) >= (select max(length(suppliername)) from suppliers) - 5 ?

Be careful with > and >= which to chose, in your example you chose the wrong one. > 33 means 34 to 38 characters; this is not "at most five characters shorter than" 38.

Move subquery from WHERE to FROM.

Select customers whose city and postalcode both appear in suppliers table. Formally - the task does not require these values to be present in the same row. You'd use 2 separate conditions (I recommend to use two WHERE EXISTS).

"at most five characters shorter" is ambiguous. Do they mean "the difference between the length and the longest length is <= 5" or "the length is <= longest length - 5"?

E.g. if the longest is 38, do they want 0-33 or 33-38?

select * 
from customers 
where exists
    (select *
    from suppliers
    where customers.city = suppliers.city and customers.postalcode = 
    suppliers.postalcode)
union
select *
from customers
where length(customername) >= 
(select max(length(suppliername)) from suppliers) - 5;

Based on your answers i made it look like this and the result set seems to be correct. Like i said, i 'am totally new to all of this and hope to pick up the basics soon. English is not my first language so that makes things a bit more interesting also.
Thank you everyone who answered my question, it was helpful and i hope that i understanded everything correctly...
